# Round a floating number to the next integer value in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

how can i round up a floating point number to the next integer value in JSP ? Suppose

2.1 -->3

3.001 -->4

4.5 -->5

7.9 -->8

Comment: Add one and drop the digits?

Comment: @Manu - That won't work for numbers that are integers to start with. You have to test for that first.

Comment: @TedHopp Right, didn't think of that case :-)

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the behaviour here should be for integers. It seems probable that `3.00 --> 3` but not entirely a given.

Comment: @dcsohl I don't understand what's unclear about [ceiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza while that seems to be the desired behavior, the OP never explicitly said ceiling is what (s)he desires.

Comment: @River again: I don't know how this is unclear. Just read here: **how can i round up a floating point number to the next integer value in JSP?**. And there are examples in the question. Please don't try to obscure any meanings.

Comment: Nobody's trying to obscure anything. If the floating point number in question is 3.0, is "round[ing] up a floating point number to the next integer value" meant to give you 3 or 4? Strictly speaking, the **next** integer value would be 4. I highly doubt this was meant, but it's the literal meaning, and the OP should clarify.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza exactly as dcsohl says

Comment: @dcsohl for me, 3.0 is 3 and it's an integer, not a floating point number. Integers fit into floating point numbers, but I don't think that's part of the question. And for me, it's very clear.